# Sudoku board check algorithm - is there anything else to check other than duplicates?

Tags: algorithm, sudoku

I made an algorithm to check if a board is illegal, it checks for duplicates in the rows, columns and sectors, it worked well for duplicates but then after a few games I got to the following board:

[image]

Which doesn't have a solution (there are no candidates for B5 and A7) but there are no duplicates. Do we always need to check if there are no candidates along with checking for duplicates? Is there anything else to check?

Comment: This case is very easy to check, just make a bitmask of all candidates for the empty cells and if any of them are empty then it's an invalid board. There may be other reasons for a board to be invalid though.

Comment: @harold what other reasons?

Comment: Lots. For example, imagine a row in which 3 empty cells have (somehow, due to the configuration of the rest of the board), each only have the possibilities {1, 2}. But two possibilities among 3 cells means that 1 cell can never get any value. This is actually easy to detect as well, there are also reasons that are hard to detect.

Comment: Just a side note: Sudoku is NP-hard (when you generalize it to squares of arbitrary side length).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checking for duplicates will let you prove obvious cases of non legal fills.

I'm afraid you have to try and solve the Sudoku board to prove a partial fill to be legal, that is to have solutions.  Finding a single solution is enough, but there might be other solutions.  Finding all solutions is not much harder.

Proving that there are no solutions is easy for the case you provide, a single step leads to failure (all possible solutions for cell A7 produce a duplicate) but may be more complex in the general case, as it requires mutiple steps.

A brute force approach, such as trying every possibility for every empty square and recursing, has a horrible complexity. You can find shortcut approaches on the Internet and investigate them with you own code.

**Edit:** When in doubt, try brute force!  Sudoku may be NP-Complete in the general case, but in practice it does not seem to diverge significantly.  I reflected on my initial analysis above and decided to give it a try with brute force. I wrote a small program to solve Sudokus given on the command line. Even on my old MacBook Air, it solves everything I tried in less than a few milliseconds.

**Edit again:** I updated the code with a generic version that uses a better algorithm and is close to 80 times faster.

Here is the code:

```
/* Generic Sudoku solver by Charles Gordon */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef GEN
#define GEN   3
#endif
#define SIZE  (GEN*GEN)

typedef unsigned char u8_t;
typedef unsigned long long llu_t;

static int print_count = 0, print_solutions = 1;

/* utility arrays to dispatch cell number to signature arrays */
static int rowsig[SIZE * SIZE], colsig[SIZE * SIZE], regsig[SIZE * SIZE];

static void sigcell_init() {
    for (int i = 0, row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++, i++) {
            rowsig[i] = row;
            colsig[i] = SIZE + col;
            regsig[i] = SIZE + SIZE + (row / GEN) * GEN + (col / GEN);
        }
    }
}

static void print_board(const int *board, const char *header) {
    printf("%s:\n", header);
    for (int i = 0, row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++, i++)
            printf("%*.0d", 2 + (SIZE > 9) + (SIZE > 99), board[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static int validate_board(const int *board, u8_t sigs[3 * SIZE][SIZE]) {
    memset(sigs, 0, 3 * SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(sigs[0][0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE * SIZE; i++) {
        int val = board[i];
        if (val == 0)
            continue;
        if (val < 0 || val > SIZE)
            return 2;  /* found invalid value */
        val -= 1;
        if (sigs[rowsig[i]][val] | sigs[colsig[i]][val] | sigs[regsig[i]][val])
            return 1;  /* found duplicate */
        sigs[rowsig[i]][val] = sigs[colsig[i]][val] = sigs[regsig[i]][val] = 1;
    }
    return 0;  /* board is valid */
}

static llu_t try_board(int *board, u8_t sigs[3 * SIZE][SIZE], int *empty, int emp) {
    llu_t count, total = 0;
    int n, cell;
    u8_t *rowsigp, *colsigp, *regsigp;

    if (emp == 0) {
        if (print_solutions)
            print_board(board, "found a board solution");
        return 1;
    }

    cell = *empty; /* next cell to try and populate */
    rowsigp = sigs[rowsig[cell]];
    colsigp = sigs[colsig[cell]];
    regsigp = sigs[regsig[cell]];
    for (n = 0; n < SIZE; n++) {
        /* check if value is possible */
        if ((rowsigp[n] | colsigp[n] | regsigp[n]) == 0) {
            rowsigp[n] = colsigp[n] = regsigp[n] = 1;
            board[cell] = n + 1;
            if ((count = try_board(board, sigs, empty + 1, emp - 1)) > 0) {
                total += count;
                if (!print_count)
                    break;
            }
            rowsigp[n] = colsigp[n] = regsigp[n] = 0;
            board[cell] = 0;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int board[SIZE * SIZE];   /* board values: empty=0 */
    u8_t sigs[3 * SIZE][SIZE];  /* signatures for row, col and regions */
    int empty[SIZE * SIZE];   /* list of empty cells */
    int i, n;
    llu_t count = 0;

    sigcell_init();

    /* initialize board */
    for (i = 1, n = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-a")) {
            print_count = 1;
            print_solutions = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if (n < SIZE * SIZE)
            board[n++] = atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    while (n < SIZE * SIZE)
        board[n++] = 0;

    print_board(board, "initial board");

    if (validate_board(board, sigs)) {
        printf("board is invalid\n");
        return 1;
    }
    /* compute list of empty cells */
    for (i = n = 0; i < SIZE * SIZE; i++) {
        if (board[i] == 0)
            empty[n++] = i;
    }
    if ((count = try_board(board, sigs, empty, n)) == 0) {
        printf("board does not have solutions\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (print_count) {
        printf("total board solutions: %llu\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Passing a command line option of `-a` makes the program look of all solutions and print the total number found.  As expected, the timings grow exponentially with the number of empty cells.  But they only become significant when the board is less than half full and has many solutions.

Comment: Can you document the bit operations please? For example, what is this: `sig[sigcell[i][0]] |= bit`?

Comment: I have updated the code.  Maybe it would be more readable to have 3 separate dispatch arrays for row, col and region signatures.

Comment: I updated the code again with separate dispatch arrays and a better signature based algorithm: **100 times** faster.

Comment: What makes it 100 times faster? also why use the bit operations when you can hold the values as they were or make a boolean array such that an index with a 1 means that the digit: index + 1 has appeared?

Comment: It is 100x faster because I no longer verify the whole grid for duplicates for each try, I only check values that can I can legally use in the current cell.  The bit masks are efficient for checking possible values quickly: you can combine sets from the row, col and region in one operation.  It would be more work with boolean arrays, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: I haven't gotten to learn bit operations yet so I don't think I understand that part well. I'll be back (after I'll learn it).

Comment: I changed the code to use boolean arrays. It is a little slower but no longer limited to 64x64 grids.  I updated the code.